# how to show whether there are non-real roots in the unit disc of this equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, roots

For the equation $e^z=e^2z$, $|z|\leq 1$.

I have shown there are no roots on the imaginary axis and boundary of the unit disc by simple computing.

And let $z=x+iy$ ($x^2+y^2\leq 1$). $e^z=e^2z$ gives $$e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)=e^2(x+iy)$$.

Thus we have $$
  \
    \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  e^x\cos y=e^2x\\
                 \\
                  e^x\sin y =e^2 y
                \end{array}
              \right.
  \
$$

Manipulating this will give $e^{2x}=e^4(x^2+y^2)$ and $\tan y =\frac{y}{x}$. But I can neither give a contradiction nor prove there are roots given above formulas.

Considering this is a complex analysis question, maybe there are other ways of doing it instead of elementary ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try applying Rouché's Theorem to $f(z)=e^z-e^2z$ on the unit disc.